# Is there a void version of Lazy<T>?

Tags: .net, lazy-initialization

I want to use the behavior of `Lazy<T>` in my class to make sure that a certain operation happens once and only once.  I have done this before by having a Lazy that essentially calls a Func that does something and then returns a null value.  I don't care about the return value, I just want to make sure the thing only happens once.

I'm thinking it could be called `Once`.  I'll build it myself and use a `Lazy` internally if it doesn't already exist, but I thought ask before doing that.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious about the reason for this. Because you're not interested in the return value, why would you call this "Function" multiple times but only want it to be executed one time?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, couldn't you just use the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: There is some initialization logic that I would normally just call in the constructor, but I prefer to avoid making calls to my dependencies in the constructor since that can lead to problems when using DI.

Comment: Instead, I wanted to defer this initialization until the first time one of the methods is called.  It's easy to use a Lazy<T> for this, just wondering if there was a way to not waste the T.  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not exist yet. Use a `Lazy<object>` and return `null` from the factory.

You can encapsulate that into a `Once` class like you said but don't inherit from `Lazy<object>` because that would be a misuse of inheritance. Use proper encapsulation.

You can also use the [`LazyInitializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazyinitializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks.  Definitely will not use inheritance for this.  I'll just have a `Lazy<object>` field on `Once`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need absolute control over *when* the initialization occurs, you could use a static constructor of one of your classes. Otherwise you could use the following:

You can either use `Lazy<T>` or [`LazyInitializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazyinitializer.aspx). Here is an example of the latter.

```
private object _initializationObject;

// this is used to ensure the initialization function only runs once, even in
// multi-threaded scenarios
private bool _initialized;
private readonly object _initializationLock = new object();

private void Initialize()
{
  // run the initialization once
  LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(
    ref _initializationObject, ref _initialized,
    _initializationLock, InitializeImpl);
}

private object InitializeImpl()
{
  // initialization code...

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Love it.  However it ends up being way too much code and it still has a generic requirement like `Lazy<T>` and I have no such requirement.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, are great ideas to achieve what you want

1) Use `Lazy<object>` returns null..

2) Use `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized<T>` returns null too..

3) Use a Singleton Pattern or something like it...

But I recommend another approach

Use Task initialization, you can check more details here:
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

The basics ideia is to create a task, you do not necessary need perform asynchronous, you only need to wait for its completed, and if it is completed, the method proceeds directly.

All ways are very similar, feel free to choose the one which fits in your solution.

Comment: Thanks.  `Task`s seem a little too much for this in my opinion.