# what is the correct way to create a pop-up window which contains a method that only executes only when the first time it loads in WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my project I have a method in a pop-up window. This method should be executed only the first time when the pop-up window is loaded. That is to say, when I open the window several times, the method only runs in its first round. What is the correct way to implement it?

The description of the code is as follows:

1. The Form has a comboBox
2. comboBox.SelectedValueChanged is associated with a Method ApplyPropertyGrid:  `this.comboBoxEx1.SelectedValueChanged += ApplyPropertyGrid;`
3. In method ApplyPropertyGrid, there's the sub-method `MyMethod` that is needed only execute once:

`private void ApplyPropertyGrid(object sender, EventArgs e) {...... ...... MyMethod() ......}`

Comment: What `MyMethod` is doing? If it's initialization, then static constructor may fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Lazy` delegate is guaranteed to fire exactly once. Even if your application is multi-threaded.

The one catch is that you [must return something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457090/is-there-a-void-version-of-lazyt), although you could just throw the result away. In my example, `MyMethod` simply returns `true`.

If you make it static, it will load only once for all instances of that particular form.

For your ApplyPropertyGrid method to be sure it has run, just get its value.

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    static Lazy<bool> _runOnce = new Lazy<bool>(MyMethod);

    static bool MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This will run only once!");
        return true;
    }

    private void ApplyPropertyGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isInitialized = _runOnce.Value;
        //You can be sure at this point that MyMethod has executed exactly once
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use a static bool Flag:

```
private static bool isExecuted = false
.....

if (!isExecuted )

            {
                MyMethod();
                isExecuted = true;
            }
```

Comment: While this might work in your specific case, this approach is not thread-safe. The `static Lazy` delegate approach suggested by @JohnWu is a better general solution

Comment: @CoolBots, boolean flag are very common. `Lazy<T>` require returning value and return just something is a code-smell (may confuse later reviewers, especially in environment where not everything can be intellisense-tracked, e.g. wpf xaml, could be easily solved with comment, but still). Unless threading is a topic, this approach is fine.